# Using a class to test another class?

Tags: java

For the given class below, I was asked to test this class with a new `TimeTest` class that has a method `doTest()` to try out these methods in my `Time` class. I have tested classes before via the `main` method, but I have no idea how to test a class using a class. Could anyone help me get started?

```
public class Time {

    private int minute;
    private int hour;
    private int totalMinute;

    public Time() {
        minute = 0;
        hour = 0;
    }

    public Time(int hours, int minutes) {
        setHour(hours);
        setMinute(minutes);
    }

    private void setHour(int hours) {
        if (hours < 24 && hours >= 0) {
            hour = hours;
        } else {
            hour = 0;
        }
    }

    private void setMinute(int minutes) {
        if (minutes < 60 && minutes >= 0) {
            minute = minutes;
        } else {
            minute = 0;
        }
    }

    public void setTime(int hours, int minutes) {
        setHour(hours);
        setMinute(minutes);
    }

    public int getElapsedTime(Time that) {
        int thisTime = this.getTotalMinutes();
        int thatTime = that.getTotalMinutes();
        if (thisTime > thatTime) {
            return thisTime - thatTime;
        }
        return thatTime - thisTime;
    }

    private int getTotalMinutes() {
        totalMinute = (hour * 60) + minute;

        return totalMinute;
    }

    public String getAsString() {
        if (hour < 10 && minute < 10) {
            return "0" + hour + ":0" + minute;
        } else if (hour < 10 && minute >= 10) {
            return "0" + hour + ":" + minute;
        } else if (hour >= 10 && minute < 10) {
            return hour + ":0" + minute;
        } else {
            return hour + ":" + minute;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using JUnit is a good practice.  There are other test harness suites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the class which may meet your requirement. If you do not want main method in this class then write the main method in another class and Create object of TimeTest and call the doTest(time) method from that class which has main method.

```
public class TimeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Time time = new Time();
    time.setTime(10, 10);
    doTest(time);

}

private static void doTest(Time time) {
    //set the time to 10 hours and 10 minutes
    System.out.println("Get as String: " + time.getAsString());
    // set the new time to test the getElapsedTime(time) method
    Time newTime = new Time(11, 30);
    System.out.println("Get Elapsed Time: " + time.getElapsedTime(newTime) + " minutes");
}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Junit](http://www.junit.org/) is the best place to start testing your logics.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JUnit](https://github.com/kentbeck/junit/wiki).  It can provide you with an easy-to-use testing environment.

The main concept when you're testing your code - a test should only ever assert one thing.  What that thing *is* depends on your code.

Here's an example of a test on your current class.  I wish to assert that, after setting your `Time` class to 1:13, I will return that exact String.  This test should live in its *own* class, independent of your `Time` object.

```
@Test
public void testGetAsString() {
    Time testObj = new Time();
    String expected = "01:13";
    testObj.setTime(1, 13);
    String result = testObj.getAsString();
    Assert.assertEquals("the time isn't properly rendered", result, expected);
}
```

Unit tests like this can greatly help you with larger projects, refactoring, and is one of the three parts of test-driven development.

If you're interested, you can also look into other testing frameworks which mimic, or mock, the behavior of another object. [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/), [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/), and [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) can help you in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to do whatever you did in main() in the new Test class.

So, if previously, main created a new object of the class and then called methods on that object, your Test class would create a new object of the original class and call its methods.

Something like:

```
public class TimeTest
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      Time timeA = new Time();
      Time timeB = new Time(12, 30);
      System.out.println("Time Diff: " + timeB.getElapsedTime(timeA);
      //  etc
   }
}
```

Once you've got this, investigate the different testing frameworks, like JUnit, which automatically deal with the administrative side of testing, allowing you to do tests like you do code.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out JUnit framework.

The test class should look like this:

```
public class TimeTest {

    public TimeTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test

    public void doTest()
    {
        Time instance = new Time();
        //your code to test the methods
        //use assertEquals(expectedResult, result) to compare the result you expected                with the result from your code  
    }

}
```

Comment: I really don't see a reason to do any pre- or post-prep work.  It's a really simple class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TimeTest
{

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   doTest();

  }

  public static void doTest()
  {
   Time t1=new Time();

   Time t2=new Time(12,45);

   System.out.printf("%s\n",t1.getAsString());
   System.out.printf("%s",t2.getAsString());

  }


}// end of class TimeTest
```

That is how you can try other methods of class time in method doTest of class TimeTest

Answer (score -1):

Write another testclass inside that class use a main function. and from that main function test the class.

You need to test your time class? am I right?

```
 public class test
 {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
        Time t = new Time();

       //now use any method of time class
        //i.e. t.methodname(pram)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate this a little bit?

Comment: How do you intend to expand this into actual tests, and assert things that are true about the state of an object after the tested methods are called?

Comment: This is just a homework. he is doing the basic coding now. And you are telling him about jUnit or sthing other!! Ehhhhh

Comment: Sorry but i found other answers much more helpful